# Converting data to long format -- other variables inserted between observations

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe in R:

```
ID            Count  
31/10/2019       15
01                1
02                2
03                5
04                7
01/11/2019       14
01                1
02                4
03                5
04                5
02/11/2019       10
01                1
02                2
03                3
04                4
```

I would like to change it to:

```
ID            Count    Date
01                1    31/10/2019
02                2    31/10/2019
03                5    31/10/2019
04                7    31/10/2019
01                1    01/11/2019
02                4    01/11/2019
03                5    01/11/2019
04                5    01/11/2019
01                1    02/11/2019
02                2    02/11/2019
03                3    02/11/2019
04                4    02/11/2019
```

I was thinking of using gather but I'm not sure how. Can someone help me out please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a new column `Date` where the value is `ID` if `Color` column is empty else `NA`, `fill` the `Date` Column and remove empty values from `Color` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = ifelse(Color == "", ID, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Date) %>%
  filter(Color != "")

#   ID Color       Date
#1  01  blue 31/10/2019
#2  02  cyan 31/10/2019
#3  03   red 31/10/2019
#4  04 black 31/10/2019
#5  01  blue 01/11/2019
#6  02  cyan 01/11/2019
#7  03   red 01/11/2019
#8  04 black 01/11/2019
#9  01  blue 02/11/2019
#10 02  cyan 02/11/2019
#11 03   red 02/11/2019
#12 04 black 02/11/2019
```